SSMS 20 Extension: could not load Microsoft.VisualStudio.Interop
I have tried to develop SSMS extension (Add-In) using this way
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1377559/How-to-Create-SQL-Server-Management-Studio-18-SSMS
It works when I run VS2022 and debug the extension using SSMS.exe.
It is ok, But when I have copied folder to SSMS and run SSMS I have an error:
"Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.Interop, Version=17.0.0.0"
How to fix it?
